# Add item with color to CheckBoxList or ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkboxlist, listboxitem

I am adding an item from two `TextBox` on `Button_Click` to `Checkboxlist` (or to a `Listbox`) with `checkedListBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text);` but it obviously will just add the text itself not its properties like color or font and ... .

Question:  How can i add items with their properties (like color and ...) to a checkboxlist or listbox?

Comment: Item can be any object. So you can create a custom class having some properties and add instances of that class to `Items` collection.

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei you made my mind clearer, going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add($"<font color=\"red\">{"String from your two fields"}</font>");
```

Comment: Tried `checkedListBox1.Items.Add($"<font color=\"red\">{textBox1.Text}</font>");` and `listBox1.Items.Add("<font color=\"red\">{textBox1.Text}</font>");` but this will put `<font color=\"red\">{textBox1.Text}</font>` or `<font color=\"red\">{textBox1.Text}</font>` as text. seems the html wont work on wfa.